# data-ng-repeat and <option> tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to `AngularJS` and I cant figure out how to generate my `<option> list`.

My desired output is like this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XdpJv/

My current code looks like this

```
<select data-ng-model="rateFilter" data-ng-change="filterStuff()">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Show lowest rating</option>
    <option value="{{rate}}" data-ng-repeat="rate in ratings">{{rate}}</option>
    <option value="{{rate}}+" data-ng-repeat="rate in ratings">{{rate}}+</option>
</select>
```

The ratings variable looks like this `[1 2 3]` and cannot be changed. How do i achieve this without changing the ratings variable?

Comment: I think its is better if you put the combined manipulated list in one different array and use it for ng-repeat. Is that possible for you? Your ratings is still intact :)

Comment: @Kop4Lyf this would work but I have to keep my memory usage as low as possible so it's not optimal.

Comment: It wont affect the memory that much. Also I was unable to find a way to do it as per the fiddle in other way. Only able to list the options as 1,2,3,4, 1+, 2+... Let me know if somehow you are able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ngOptions-directive to manage your Select-Option. Sometimes this is a little bit tricky but you should always try to make it in the angular way. You can look [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect) how it works. Important is this part:

```
for array data sources:
    label for value in array
    select as label for value in array
    label group by group for value in array
    select as label group by group for value in array track by trackexpr
for object data sources:
    label for (key , value) in object
    select as label for (key , value) in object
    label group by group for (key, value) in object
    select as label group by group for (key, value) in object
```

You have to define an Array or Object with your possible Ratings then your code can look like this:

```
<select ng-model="ratings" ng-options="label for value in possible_ratings">
</select>
```

Comment: `label` wouldn't be defined and the ng-model would overwrite his options list.  In an array of numbers, the only label available is `value` unless you're using a constant label from outside the scope of the directive.  He'll also want to continue storing the `value` of his selected option somewhere other than into his options array so `ng-model` should stay set to `rateFilter`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll actually want to use an `ng-options` attribute on your `select` tag.  Angular hijacks all `select` tags using what's called a "directive" and uses the expression in the `ng-options` attribute to generate the `option` tags for the select.  Your expression would look like:

```
<select data-ng-model="rateFilter" data-ng-change="filterStuff()"
        data-ng-options="rate for rate in ratings"></select>
```

The expression before the `for` becomes the option's label, the variable after `for` is a reference to each object, and obviously the variable after the `in` is your array.  If you want to define a custom `value` for your options, you can change the expression to

```
rate as rate+'%' for rate in ratings`
```

assuming that ratings were percentages.  If your array actually contained objects, such as a `bracket` field you could even group the options with

```
rate.percent as rate.percent+'%' group by rate.bracket for rate in ratings
```

More information about the `select` directive and the `ng-options` attribute can be found in the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect).

Essentially what you're looking at under the hood is

```
for (i in ratings) {
  rate = ratings[i];
  // insert <option value="{{rate.percent}}">{{rate.percent}}%</option>
}
```

With the `group by` breaking ratings up into separate arrays based on the value of `rate.bracket`, then adding options for each array inside an `<optgroup>` tag.

Comment: Thank you but this won't do what I want. If you look at my fiddle I want the list to contain 1,1+,2,2+ etc. Not only 1,2,3. In that case my previous solution works just fine. The important thing here is that I want "1+" right after "1" and not after "3". Is this possible without modifying my ratings list?